# how to write Test class for extension or javascript remoting class

Tags: apex, controller-extension, unit-test

Hey i write extension for my custom controller. how to write test class for this extension, in this this extension im using just one javascript remoting method?
**here is my Extension Code**

```
global with sharing class CheckExtension {
    public CheckExtension(CustomCheck controller) {    }
    @RemoteAction
    global static string getRecNumber(String Rec){
        if(Rec==1)
        return 'you Receive one  Record ';
        else
        return 'you Receive Multiple  Records';

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you already try something ? You can test them like normal controller methods, as you're testing your functionality within them, not the actual remote/communication part of the transaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call the method as you would a regular, static method.  Your test method(s) might look like:

```
@isTest
private class MyTest{
    static testmethod testRec1(){
        Test.startTest();
        String str = CheckExtension.getRecNumber('1');
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals('you receive one Record';
    }

    static testmethod testRecNot1(){
        Test.startTest();
        String str = CheckExtension.getRecNumber('2');
        Test.stopTest(0;
        System.assertEquals('you receive multiple records');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks james its work for me but code coverage us 35 % how to increase it to 75% ?